# NSJSONSerialization vs stream based parser

Tags: ios, json, ios5, memory-management, nsjsonserialization

My iPad app needs to parse a 10 MB JSON file and save its contents in Core Data.

Would you recommend using `NSJSONSerialization` considering the large file size and memory usage or would you rather choose a **stream based** JSON parser (which stream based parser would you recommend in this case)? By the way: The file has been created with `NSJSONSerialization` by another iOS app.

Thank you!

Comment: If by "stream based" you mean a parser similar to some XML parsers where you "ask" for a particular bit of data and it's extracted "on the fly", vs parsing the entire file and returning the resulting data in one "chunk", there are few JSON parsers of that type.  This is in large part because the internal representation of parsed JSON is much more compact than the typical internal representation of XML, so it's more practical to parse it all at once.  (Plus, you can't guarantee the order of items in a JSON object like you can with XML.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend both, because `NSJSONSerialization` has the method `JSONObjectWithStream:options:error:`.

---

You could instead use [this JSON parsing framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/).

Comment: But the dictionary structure built from the parser would allocate 10 MB of RAM right after the parse process has been completed? Wouldn`t that result in iOS memory warnings?

Comment: That depends what it is and how it's formatted. 10MB of JSON text doesn't necessarily equate to 10MB of data in memory. If it's going to be large in memory then you don't want to load (so you don't want to parse) the whole thing at any point in time.

Comment: In general, parsed representation of a JSON file will be more than a little larger (probably 3-5x) than the source file.  There is very little "sugar" in JSON, and all of the strings in JSON need to be represented in the parser output.  Strings will be expanded to 2-byte or 4-byte representations, plus they have object overhead, and the overhead to manage the language's arrays and dictionaries.